# toString() method is not overridden when a reference to Annotation is output in println()

Tags: java

```
package javaapplication20;
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyAnno {
    String str();
    int yu();
}
@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Wasp {
    double hg();
}
@MyAnno(str = "Falcon", yu=5 )
@Wasp(hg = 54.67)
public class Main {
        @MyAnno(str = "Raptor", yu=7 )
        @Wasp(hg = 90.56)
public static void meth(){
            Main ob = new Main();
            try{
                Annotation annon[] = ob.getClass().getAnnotations();
                System.out.println("All anotations for Main are ");
                for(Annotation a : annon){
                    System.out.println(a);
                }

                Method m = ob.getClass().getMethod("meth");
                Annotation annons[] = m.getAnnotations();
                System.out.println("All Annotations for meth() are ");
                for(Annotation a : annons){
                    System.out.println(a);
                }
            }catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
                System.out.println("No Match Found");
            }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 meth();
    }

}
```

OUTPUT :

```
All anotations for Main are 
@javaapplication20.MyAnno(str=Falcon, yu=5)
@javaapplication20.Wasp(hg=54.67)
All Annotations for meth() are 
@javaapplication20.MyAnno(str=Raptor, yu=7)
@javaapplication20.Wasp(hg=90.56)
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Where have you overridden `toString`? And what is the expected output?

Comment: Is overriding done or not? In the example, the name of package is not outputted..

Comment: Annotation overrides toString() function in Object Class, I havent done that manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is hidden in the javaDoc of the `Annotation` interface. For `toString()`, it says:

> Returns a string representation of this annotation. The details of the representation are implementation-dependent, but the following may be regarded as typical:
>
> ```
> @com.acme.util.Name(first=Alfred, middle=E., last=Neuman)
> ```

And this is what you see on your output. The java compiler will create a class file for your annotation and this class file will have an implementation of `toString()` that produces this output. *Implementation-dependent* refers to the *java compiler*, not to your implementation of an annotation.

Comment: Really the *Java compiler*, not the JRE? I thought the compiler generates only interfaces for the Annotation types, while the runtime environment then has to generate implementations (using Proxies or similar).

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is;

Does an @Annotation have a default implementation for toString()?

The answer is yes.  It also has a default implementation for hashCode() and equals().

Comment: I was just asking, does the name of the package appear before the object a of type Annotation?

Comment: That is in that defaul implementation, name of package also appears? 'Cause in the example from where i read, it was not there.

Comment: This question was a challenge ;) Needed your answer to understand it...